# What is AddEndpointsApiExplorer in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-6.0, aspnet-api-versioning

I'm upgrading an ASP.NET Core API project from v5 to v6.

Service config in [v5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=netcore-cli#add-and-configure-swagger-middleware-1):

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen();
```

Service config in [v6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=netcore-cli#add-and-configure-swagger-middleware):

```cs
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();    // what is this?
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
```

What is `AddEndpointsApiExplorer`? Everything works as expected whether I add it or not.

I use the "ASP.NET API Versioning" [library](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning). Are they related? If so, must I use both, just the library, or is the library unnecessary now?

Comment: I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.endpointmetadataapiexplorerservicecollectionextensions.addendpointsapiexplorer?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: The source of this tutorial is different from the published docs https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle.md#add-and-configure-swagger-middleware-1 which suggests that if you call `AddMvc` the api explorer services are added for you, but a minimum api setup may not.

Comment: Hmmm `AddEndpointsApiExplorer` is new in v6, the implementation is slightly different to `AddApiExplorer`. It's surprising that the functionality wasn't merged into the same method. It appears to exist to provide endpoint metadata for "Minimal Api's" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`AddEndpointsApiExplorer` is for *Minimal APIs* whereas `AddApiExplorer` requires, at least, MVC Core. For API projects, `AddControllers` calls `AddApiExplorer` on your behalf.

**But Why Does Everything Still Work With `AddEndpointsApiExplorer`?**

With the introduction of *Endpoint Routing*, everything in the routing system boils down to an `Endpoint`. ASP.NET Core uses the *Application Model*, namely `ApplicationModel`, `ControllerModel` and `ActionModel` to create `Endpoint` instances and register them with the routing system. *Minimal APIs*, however, use a builder to directly create and register individual `Endpoint` instances.

The default API Explorer implementation provides a `IApiDescriptionProvider` that builds `ApiDescription` instances from the *Application Model*. *Minimal APIs* do not have an *Application Model* so there is nothing to build `ApiDescription` instances from. The API Explorer provides these descriptions, which are commonly used by tools such as OpenAPI generators. Without any descriptions, there would be no support for *Minimal APIs* and OpenAPI; that would be bad (or, at least, certainly not accepted by developers). To address that, the ASP.NET Core team created a second `IApiDescriptionProvider` that only considers `Endpoint`.

**If Everything is an `Endpoint`, Why Not Merge Implementations?**

There're two parts to this answer. First, changing the original `IApiDescriptionProvider` implementation would introduce a public, breaking change. At a minimum, new constructor arguments would be required. Since it was a major version bump, this approach wasn't off the table, but it turns out to be irrelevant. The bigger issue is that the original `IApiDescriptionProvider` implementation and `AddApiExplorer` live in and depend on MVC Core. *Minimal APIs* only require the routing abstractions. There is no way to merge the two without adding unnecessary coupling. To address this problem, `AddEndpointsApiExplorer` was added which adds an implementation that only requires an `IApiDescriptionProvider` implementation based on bare bones `Endpoint` definitions from the routing system.

If `AddEndpointsApiExplorer` exists and I call it, do I even need `AddApiExplorer` anymore? Maybe. The metadata exposed and available on *Minimal API* `Endpoint` instances is much lighter than the *Application Model*; after all, they are *minimal*. Behind the scenes, a `IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider` implementation takes a sequence of `IApiDescriptionProvider` instances. If `AddEndpointsApiExplorer` and `AddApiExplorer` are called, then both providers will execute. If only `AddEndpointsApiExplorer` is called, it will work with regular 'ol controllers, but the descriptions' information fidelity *might* be less than what you are accustomed to. If you are only authoring *Minimal APIs*, then `AddEndpointsApiExplorer` is required if you want API Explorer support.

> The fidelity between the two methods is improving even more in .NET 7.0. In some future release, it's possible we *might* see these approaches coalesce into one.

Answer (score 23):

TLDR; `.AddEndpointsApiExplorer()` was created to support [Minimal Api's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Searching the doc's via google shows a number of pages that include a call to `.AddEndpointsApiExplorer()`. But no mention of why you need it, or if it is required when migrating from a v5 project. The documentation is definitely lacking.

Working backwards from the source code & [git blame](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blame/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.ApiExplorer/src/DependencyInjection/EndpointMethodInfoApiExplorerServiceCollectionExtensions.cs), I found the [related project](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/projects/18). So the answer appears to be related to support for [Minimal Api's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

I believe some new services were created to extract return type information from these new minimal api's, in a way that might apply in a more general way when using Endpoint Routing without MVC.

If you are using MVC, perhaps via `.AddControllers()`, `.AddApiExplorer()` would be called for you. Providing the services that swagger depends on for describing controller actions. If that's all you need, then this new api call doesn't seem to be required.

While the documentation for using [swagger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#openapi) with minimal api's includes a call to `.AddEndpointsApiExplorer()`. Even that doesn't explain exactly why it is required.

Why does `.AddEndpointsApiExplorer()` exist at all? Why were the new features excluded from `.AddApiExplorer()`? Why was this method rename left out of other documentation for v6?

Perhaps we should create an issue on https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/ or https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/ to ask for clarification so that others don't have to ask these questions.

Comment: Thanks! Wow I wish there were a "code archaeologist" tag, because that's what you deserve. :-) Thanks for digging into this. It's definitely for minimal APIs, I confirmed with @ChrisMartinez [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/819). But the issues from the asp.net side are still there - I'll create an issue on the docs repo as you suggested.

Comment: Added [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/25685) to repo.

Comment: You guys are typing faster than I can respond. =D Comprehensive explanation below. If you really, really want to go down the rabbit hole, I can dig up the links in the ASP.NET Core repo where these things happen. Let me know and I'll update my answer. Hopefully, that provides some clarity.

Answer (score 9):

TL;DR

Only use `AddEndpointsApiExplorer` if you use v6's "minimal APIs", which look like this:

```cs
app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
```